# How is it possible to sort ps command's CPU field?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sort, ps

I'm trying to make a small command that will find the processes that use the most CPU power.

Firstly, I use `ps aux > file.txt` and then `cut -c 16-20 file.txt | sort -n | tail -5`.

The result I get is this:

```
1.0 
2.7
8.
14.5
14.5
```

So my question is how can I have both the `%CPU` usage and the other fields outputted together?

Comment: Why not use `top` instead?

Comment: @JosephR. I just wanna use the commands that I just learned for text processing on this small 'script'.

Comment: Well, if you're doing it as a sort of exercise, then you might want to look at `awk`. Afterwards, when you're ready to move things "to production", you should use `top` in batch mode if it's suitable for your requirements.

Comment: You can also eliminate the intermediate `file.txt` by doing `ps aux|cut -c ...`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The correct answer is:

```
ps --sort=-pcpu
```

For top 5:

```
ps --sort=-pcpu | head -n 6
```

So you can specify columns without interfering with sorting.

Ex:

```
ps -Ao user,uid,comm,pid,pcpu,tty --sort=-pcpu | head -n 6
```

---

Note of 'ckujau': `--sort` is supported by `ps` from `procps`, other implementations may not have this option.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: Please note that ```--sort``` is only supported by ```ps``` from ```procps```, other implementations may not have this option.

Comment: Thank you 'ckujau' for noting this. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 18):

Sort on the appropriate field (by default defined as whitespace to non-whitespace transition), in my case it is the 3rd one:

```
ps aux | sort -n -k 3
```

Comment: This isn't as good as @Facundo's answer, because if you change the visible columns, you'll have to also change the sort key.

Comment: @JonathanHartley yes, but only if your `ps` has the `--sort` option.

Comment: Fair enough. And a minimum comment length.

Answer (score 7):

One annoyance with the accepted solution is that the headers for the different columns will get included in the output. Another issue being that when you use the switch `-x` to `ps` it will provide the full command lines for some programs, which can run on and become a nuisance in the output.

#### For example

1. Annoying command-lines

   > saml     18174  7.3  3.2 1174896 259756 ?      Sl   Aug27 132:38
   >   /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --lang=en-US
   >   --force-fieldtrials=AsyncDns/AsyncDnsB/ForceCompositingMode/disable/InfiniteCache/No/OmniboxHQPReplaceHUPProhibitTrumpingInlineableResult/Standard/OmniboxSearchSuggestTrialStarted2013Q1/7/OneClickSignIn/Standard/Prerender/PrerenderControl/SendFeedbackLinkLocation/default/Test0PercentDefault/group_01/UMA-Dynamic-Binary-Uniformity-Trial/default/UMA-Session-Randomized-Uniformity-Trial-5-Percent/group_17/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-1-Percent/group_20/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-10-Percent/group_07/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-20-Percent/default/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-5-Percent/group_04/UMA-Uniformity-Trial-50-Percent/group_01/
   >   --enable-crash-reporter=4061BD10D0DC127169CE2132BC3FF8EC,Fedora release 14 (Laughlin) --extension-process --renderer-print-preview
   >   --disable-webgl --disable-pepper-3d --disable-gl-multisampling --disable-accelerated-compositing --disable-accelerated-2d-canvas --disable-accelerated-video-decode --channel=18086.4.1423385819
   >
   > root      1764  7.7  0.3 163692 28928 tty1     Ss+  Aug21 817:49 /usr/bin/Xorg
   >   :0 -nr -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-fADI0V/database
   >   -nolisten tcp vt1

   Chrome especially can be quite annoying when looking at `ps` output like this!
2. Headers in output

   ```
   $ ps auf | sort -nk 3 | head -20
   ...
   root      1741  0.0  0.0   4140   400 tty5     Ss+  Aug21   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5
   root      1743  0.0  0.0   4140   400 tty6     Ss+  Aug21   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6
   saml     13780  0.0  0.0 115088  4216 pts/13   Ss   Aug27   0:00 bash
   saml     20432  0.0  0.0   6308   400 pts/9    S+   Aug27   0:00  \_ inotifywatch -e CREATE /etc
   saml      8206  0.0  0.0 115296  1108 pts/6    Ss+  Aug21   0:03 bash
   USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
   saml     29352  0.1  0.5 661848 42960 pts/13   Sl+  17:59   0:18  \_ irb
   ...
   ```

   You can see the header mixed in at the 7th line in the output.

#### Alternatives

1. Getting rid of the headers

   `ps` provides a switch for disabling the display of these column headers. It's pretty easy to use, simply add the `--no-heading` switch.

   ```
   $ ps aux --no-heading | sort -nk 3 | head -10
   68        1481  0.0  0.0  38592  2144 ?        Ssl  Aug21   0:28 hald
   68        1527  0.0  0.0  18016   672 ?        S    Aug21   0:01 /usr/libexec/hald-addon-acpi
   avahi     1333  0.0  0.0  27872  1172 ?        S    Aug21   0:01 avahi-daemon: running [grinchy.local]
   avahi     1334  0.0  0.0  27752    20 ?        S    Aug21   0:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
   dbus      1307  0.0  0.0  22716  1900 ?        Ss   Aug21   1:03 dbus-daemon --system
   gdm       1879  0.0  0.0 317220  2740 ?        Sl   Aug21   0:00 /usr/libexec/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
   ntp       3060  0.0  0.0  32600  2152 ?        Ss   20:05   0:00 ntpd -u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g
   root         1  0.0  0.0  19420  1004 ?        Ss   Aug21   0:01 /sbin/init
   root      1006  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   0:00 [kvm-irqfd-clean]
   root      1020  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Aug21   2:02 [kdmflush]
   ```

   Or like this:

   ```
   $ ps auf --no-heading | sort -nk 3 |head -10
   root      1735  0.0  0.0   4140   400 tty2     Ss+  Aug21   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2
   root      1737  0.0  0.0   4140   400 tty3     Ss+  Aug21   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3
   root      1739  0.0  0.0   4140   400 tty4     Ss+  Aug21   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty4
   root      1741  0.0  0.0   4140   400 tty5     Ss+  Aug21   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5
   root      1743  0.0  0.0   4140   400 tty6     Ss+  Aug21   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6
   saml     13780  0.0  0.0 115088  4216 pts/13   Ss   Aug27   0:00 bash
   saml     20432  0.0  0.0   6308   400 pts/9    S+   Aug27   0:00  \_ inotifywatch -e CREATE /etc
   saml      2098  0.0  0.0 115508  3148 pts/9    Ss   Aug22   0:05 bash
   saml     27134  0.0  0.0 115496  6768 pts/18   Ss   Aug27   0:02 bash
   saml      3248  0.0  0.0 115076  1024 pts/0    Ss+  Aug21   0:00 bash
   ```
2. Take control of the columns being displayed.

   This can seem like a pain, but if you're scripting the capture of `ps` output it isn't too bad. A command like this will mimic the output of `ps aux`, except swap out the longer form of the `COMMAND` column with a shorter version that just shows the executable's name.

   ```
   $ ps ax --no-headings -o user,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,sgi_rss,tname,stat,start_time,time,ucmd
   ```

   Putting it all together without the column headers it's much easier to deal with when scripting.

   *List of highest to lowest % CPU processes:*

   ```
   $ ps ax --no-headings -o user,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,sgi_rss,tname,stat,start_time,time,ucmd |sort -nrk 3|head -10
   saml     18086  114  6.4 1418852 515236 ?     Sl   Aug27 1-10:53:31 chrome
   saml     18536 14.7  4.1 1276240 328636 ?     Sl   Aug27 04:29:21 chrome
   saml     18558 12.2  3.4 1209712 278228 ?     Sl   Aug27 03:44:22 chrome
   saml     18543 10.9  3.8 1238132 308824 ?     Rl   Aug27 03:20:18 chrome
   root      1764  7.7  0.4 170220 35276 tty1    Rs+  Aug21 13:40:16 Xorg
   saml     18174  7.3  3.0 1167728 241728 ?     Sl   Aug27 02:14:25 chrome
   saml     18314  3.6  1.4 1049020 119308 ?     Sl   Aug27 01:06:19 chrome
   saml     18528  2.7  3.1 1178368 251212 ?     Sl   Aug27 00:50:55 chrome
   saml      2389  2.0  0.1 330632 8480 ?        Sl   Aug21 03:37:13 compiz
   saml     18208  1.7  1.3 1081132 108828 ?     Sl   Aug27 00:32:02 chrome
   ```

   *List of lowest to highest % CPU processes:*

   ```
   $ ps ax --no-headings -o user,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,sgi_rss,tname,stat,start_time,time,ucmd |sort -nk 3|tail -10
   saml     18208  1.7  1.3 1082156 108348 ?     Sl   Aug27 00:32:03 chrome
   saml      2389  2.0  0.1 330632 8492 ?        Sl   Aug21 03:37:15 compiz
   saml     18528  2.7  3.1 1181440 250856 ?     Sl   Aug27 00:50:58 chrome
   saml     18314  3.6  1.5 1050044 119828 ?     Sl   Aug27 01:06:25 chrome
   saml     18174  7.3  3.0 1167728 242068 ?     Sl   Aug27 02:14:32 chrome
   root      1764  7.7  0.3 163688 28716 tty1    Ss+  Aug21 13:40:26 Xorg
   saml     18543 10.9  3.8 1235060 305464 ?     Sl   Aug27 03:20:32 chrome
   saml     18558 12.2  3.5 1214832 283560 ?     Sl   Aug27 03:44:34 chrome
   saml     18536 14.7  3.9 1267024 314400 ?     Sl   Aug27 04:29:39 chrome
   saml     18086  114  6.4 1412992 514856 ?     Sl   Aug27 1-10:55:28 chrome
   ```

Comment: what if i wanna group all processes from one program, like chrome has 20 processes, which would be calculated for one.

Comment: @TomSawyer - There's no way to do this w/ just vanilla `ps` you'll have to craft a script - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34985996/33204.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Mac Ecosystem (like I am) all the other solutions will need a lot of additional work. Eg. --sort or other -- options are not supported by default as others mentioned above.

The best bet is the command below:

```
 ps aux | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $11}' | sort -n -k3 -r | head -n 10
```

This prints top 10 CPU consuming processes specifically: their user that started it, PID, CPU %age, and the command that started it.

Comment: macOS `ps` has the `-r` flag to sort by CPU. I added answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/734132/141153

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, you can use the BSD-only `-r` flag to "sort by current CPU usage":

```
ps -aexro pcpu,cputime,pid,etime,user,args | head
```

---

There's also the `-m` flag to sort by "memory usage" (`man ps` doesn't say whether this is [real or shared or private memory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107/325877)).